# How to Hot Deploy Vaadin with IntelliJ and Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, vaadin

Can IntelliJ and Tomcat be configured such that when I save changes on a class, that class is recompiled and deployed to Tomcat so that when I restart the application the changes are made visible?

I've tried setting "On Update action" and "On frame dezactivation" to "update classes and resources" but it doesn't work.

Is this possible or do I need to use tools like JRebel?

I'm using IntelliJ 12.1.4

Answer (score 3):

To update a class, the application would need to be redeployed. Meaning it will drop the session and the state of the application.

JRebel does the right job here.

Answer (score 2):

Update Resources (not classes) should be enough.  But you would need to enable HotSwap in Settings also, and start the server in debug mode.

I've just written a [blog entry](http://www.hermansjavablog.eu/programming/definitive-guide-vaadin-7-maven-tomcat-intellij-idea-hotswap-deployment/) detailing all required steps for setting up a Maven project with Vaadin using hotswap deployment to Tomcat.

It works without losing the session!